# Delete option grayed out in sharepoint, User has read write permissions

Tags: delete

Hi im having an issue with a user who has all required permissions to read/write on sharepoint, but cannot delete pages she has created. when you hover over the delete option i get "this control is currently disabled". Im new to IT and still getting to Terms and would really appreciate any info i could get.

thanks

Comment: Which version of SP you are using may have an affect on what the answer might be.

Answer (score 1):

This person may have read and write permissions to list items and documents, but it sounds like she requires "Design" access to do what you are indicating she needs to do.

This article from Microsoft discusses the differences between the roles:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/default-permission-levels-HA101837459.aspx

Best of luck!

Comment: The one big thing missing from the link is: How does one go about adding Design permissions to selected users?